# Jquery If statement to check margin left of div to apply opacity to a separate id

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I've been trying to tweak things a bit to get this to work and so far I haven't been able to use jquery to check a `div`'s left margin and on the condition it is in the `left: 0px` position, to output whatever action, in my case to apply opacity to a separate div. Here's my [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8CMp/3/). In the jfiddle I want to check the gray div "trim", and on the condition it has `marginLeft: 0px`, to apply the opacity to the div "l1". Let me know if I need to explain this more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery object doesn't have `marginLeft` property, you should use `css` method, also note that `=` is a assignment operator which valuates to `true`, you should use `==` or `===` comparison operators instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#trim').css('marginLeft') == '0px' ){
        $('#l1').animate({opacity:".5"});
    } else {
        $('#l1').animate({opacity:"1"});
    }
}); // You are missing `)` here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5djZ4/

Comment: I think the opacity property values should just be numbers too, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/K8CMp/7/

Use the [jQuery .css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#trim').css("margin-left") == "0px"){
        $('#l1').animate({opacity:".5"});
    }else{
        $('#l1').animate({opacity:"1"});
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery has to translate "margin-left" to "marginLeft", so you can avoid the extra overhead by just using "marginLeft".

Answer (score -1):

Well, in the fiddle you're doing

```
$('#trim').marginLeft
```

How about this instead:

```
$('#trim').attr('marginLeft')
```

Comment: -1: `marginLeft` is not an attribute, it's a CSS property. You should use `css()` instead of `attr()`.